# How to highlight "ini files" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting, ini

How do I make Eclipse to highlight .ini files?

In the menu Window/Preferences, General/Content Types, Test/Configutation files, in the box "File associations:" I can see:

*.cfg (locked)
*.ini (locked)

but I don't know either if this has something to do with the matter, or what can I do see the ini files highlighted instead of flat-black.

Does eclipse support ini higlighting natively? How do I activate it? Or maybe do I have to install a plugin? Which one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've just found this plugin that seems to do the trick. It is a little overzealous and assigns itself to all known filetypes but editing `Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations` can solve this.

http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html

Comment: Thanks. Cannot vote up because I am too new and I still don't reach 15 of reputation, but this works like a charm!

Comment: Though it's an old plugin it works nice in latest (4.6 neon) eclipse!

Comment: I installed the plugin and there is a ini-file-association in `Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations` but it does not highlight the file. Have anyone an idea why it don't work? btw, i am using eclipse mars (4.5.1)